# Google API Spreadsheets with service account

Tags: .net, google-api, google-sheets, google-api-dotnet-client

I can't figure out how to use Google API Spreadsheets with a Service Account (in a .NET context).

I figure using the ServiceAccountCredential is the way to go, but cannot create a SpreadsheetsService from it. The Sheets API documentation does not mention anything (support or no-support) for service accounts. Alot of examples i find also seem to be using deprecated or obsolte libraries.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Can someone bring clarity?